# "Awfully" or "awful"?

Tags: word-choice

*Awfully* is a word, as noted in [Merriam-Webster's definition of awful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awful). I recently said this:

> Your snoring is **awfully** bad.

I was in a group, and the majority agreed that *awful* was correct:

> Your snoring is **awful** bad.

Which is correct: *awful bad* or *awfully bad*, and why?

Comment: This sounds a bit like peeving disguised as a question, which is [out of scope](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) per the FAQ. Could you possibly edit this so that it is more on topic?

Comment: It might be a corruption of [this misguided and misspelled grammar advice](http://www.lousywriter.com/grammar-mistakes-awful-awfully.php), that says you should not use "awfully" as an intensifier.

Comment: Who would you say, "That's awfully good!" to? To Fred Astaire, I think, when you might have been there when he had just performed a few informal minutes of one of his better numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the person who suggested you should use 'awful bad' has an awfully bad command of English and it would be an awful idea to abandon the correct use of 'awfully' as in your exemplary sentence:

> Your snoring is awfully bad.

Comment: But some people don't like "awfully" as an intensive adverb either. The Oxford American Dictionary says "careful writers" avoid it. And yet Huxley, Wilde and Kipling have used "awfully". Do they have an awfully bad command of English?

Comment: @morphail Huxley, Wilde and Kipling: English, Irish and English. Perhaps there's different usage recommendations for their side of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case we’re still pursuing this, the OED’s earliest citation for the use of *awful* as an adverb is dated 1818. There are subsequent citations from Mark Twain and Anthony Trollope.

Comment: Also interesting given Twain was American, Trollope was English and both writing around the same time.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage on awful vs awfully.](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PA877&vq=subjunctive&dq=merriam%20websters%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q&f=false)

"The intensive adverb *awfully* was attacked as a Britishicism by Richard Grant White in 1870. The Oxford American Dictionary as recently as 1980 continues the depreciation of the intensive with the remarkable claim that "careful writers" avoid it. Perhaps so, but good writers have certainly not avoided it since it became established in the mid-19th century. Some of our examples are from fiction and drama, but others are from ordinary discursive prose"

They give 14 examples of *awfully* as an intensive adverb, from writers like Wilde, Kipling, James, Huxley, Maugham.

Comment: Nice reference. And this seems to confirm the OPs comment that the grammar police dislike *awfully*: "The intensive *awfully* was attacked as a Briticism by Richard Grant White in 1870. The Oxford American Dictionary as recently as 1980 continues the deprecation of the intensive with the remarkable claim that 'careful writers' avoid it. Perhaps so, but good writers certainly have not ..."

Comment: -1 for a link with no summary, for when the link rots. Also, what's MWEDU?

Comment: Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage. Peter Shor gives a summary in his comment.

Comment: @morphail: a comment is not really an answer. Also, that's a very long entry, most of which has to do with the reduced meaning of "awful" (i.e. using it for things that really aren't that bad), rather than using "awful" as an adverb. So it would be especially important for you to summarize the part(s) that you believe answer this question. As it is, this is not an answer.

Comment: It's awfully bad luck on Diana,/
Her ponies have swallowed their bits;/
She fished down their throats with a spanner/
And frightened them all into fits.

(John Betjeman)

Answer (score 0):

What is "awful/awfully" doing here? It is modifying the adjective "bad" (telling how bad).

Which part of speech can modify an adjective? Adverbs (Adverbs modify verbs, adjectives, other adverbs.)

Which word is the adverb? "Awfully."

Comment: Does this mean you think "bloodily stupid fool" is better than "bloody stupid fool"?

Comment: Awfully is correct in the sentence provided above and clearly we would not use blodily stupid because not all words take on -ly for its suffix