# Why do we use "awfully" as an intensifier?

Tags: adverbs, intensifying-adverbs

First, consider this sentence:

> We lost the game because we played awfully.

Since "awful" means "very bad," it makes sense that "awfully" means "very badly."

Now, consider these two sentences:

> 1) Google is an awfully good search engine.
>
> 2) Bing is an awfully bad search engine.

In the second example, regardless of the adjective's connotation, "awfully" just acts as an intensifier - it simply means "very." *Why do we use "awfully" this way? How did this form of the adverb come about?*

I'd be awfully grateful if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: **Note:** this is not a duplicate of ["Awfully" or "awful"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44914/awfully-or-awful)

Comment: Would you be terribly happy to have an answer? For whatever reason (I suspect poor vocabulary) these sort of constructions are not uncommon. Interesting side note: "very, extremely" places higher in googles definition list than "very badly, unpleasantly" for the word "terribly". It wouldn't be as much fun if words just meant what they mean.

Comment: it's awfully close to a duplicate!  hah ha. njbvoot, just think of the word **AWE**.

Comment: There are many words used as 'secondary modifiers of adjectives / adverbs'. 'Intensifiers' / 'downtoners' like _very_, _extremely_, _quite_ are rarely forced into service elsewhere. However, many secondary modifiers (_hopping_ mad, _plumb_ loco, _excruciatingly_ slowly, _exorbitantly_ expensive, _extensively_ rebuilt, _finely_ attuned / divided / tuned, _firmly_ established, _fully_ justified, _fundamentally_ flawed, _gravely_ ill ...) have other roles (usually as adverbs) and/or have semantic content rather than merely being emphasisers / downtoners.

Comment: She was a wickedly beautiful and kind woman. The sinful pleasures she exudes in her kitchen is heavenly.

Answer (score 1):

Etymonline has a description of *awfully* [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=awfully)

and interestingly *terribly* [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=terribly)

I'd say *awfully* (and *terribly*) as it is used in the examples is not really the adverb of *awful* (or *terrible*) but is an intensifier that just happens to have the same spelling as the adverb.

*He played awfully*  ... adverb, he played badly.

*He played awfully badly* ... intensifier, he played very badly.

*He played awfully well* ... intensifier, he played very well.

It might be purely coincidental but I think it's rather interesting to note that both the intensifier versions are around 1830, I couldn't find if *frightfully*, which is kinda similar, appeared at the same time.

Comment: I did look for _dreadfully_, and I did look dreadfully hard, but could find no reference regarding when it became an intensifier.

Comment: According to the OED, *dreadfully* was used as an intensifier back in the 17th century; 1697: *This is dreadfully Astonishing!*

Comment: @PeterShor I found that _frightfully_ dates (as an intensifier) from 1817.

Comment: Actually, *dreadfully* dates back to earlier in the 17th century. The OED's first citation (as an intensifier) is from Shakespeare, but it wasn't clear to me that it was an intensifier; however, I can find a number of uses in the mid-17th-century in Google books.